# Unable to update Number type column of Oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I am trying to update a column of type Number(19, 2) in my Oracle database using following code in C#. However, it does not update the data in the table. Amount - is of type Number(19,2) in database and I tried replacing Varchar2 with decimal, Int64, Long but still no luck. And request.amount is of a float type.

Any tips would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
try
{

  OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand();

  command2.CommandText = "Update t_payment set amount = :amount where penalty_order_id = (select id from t_penalty_order where protokol_no = :invoiceNumber)";


  command2.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(@"invoiceNumber", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255)).Value = request.invoiceNumber;
  command2.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(@"amount", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255)).Value = request.amount; //(Convert.ToInt32 (request.amount) + paid_amount);
  command2.Connection = connection;

  command2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;


  command2.ExecuteNonQuery();


}
catch (Exception e)
{
  completePayment.code = 111;
  completePayment.message = e.Message;
  completePayment.transactionNumber = null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the statement directly on the database using a client like Toad or Oracle Sql Developer?

Comment: yes, it gets updated. Also when I replace amount = :amount with amount = 12 for example, it gets updated too

Comment: Also when I update another column of varchar2 type of the same table, I do not experience any issue either

Comment: is `protokol_no` a string or int?

Comment: protokol_no is a string

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was in the order of adding parameters. I had to add amount parameter value first and then protokol_no.